# Random Forest - How to handle overfitting

Tags: random-forest, overfitting

I have a computer science background but am trying to teach myself data science by solving problems on the internet.

I have been working on this problem for the last couple of weeks (approx 900 rows and 10 features). I was initially using logistic regression but now I have switched to random forests. When I run my random forest model on my training data I get really high values for auc (> 99%). However when I run the same model on the test data the results are not so good (Accuracy of approx 77%). This leads me to believe that I am over fitting the training data.

What are the best practices regarding preventing over fitting in random forests?

I am using r and rstudio as my development environment. I am using the `randomForest` package and have accepted defaults for all parameters

Comment: You may wish to use cross validation methods, such as K fold cross validation.

Comment: Breiman claims that RF does not overfit. http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm On the assumption that he is correct, perhaps there is some sort of inconsistency between your training and test set?

Comment: RF does AVOIDS overfit to TEST DATA *if* you optimize the tuning parameter

Comment: I find sampsize a complety overlooked tuning parameter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997134/random-forest-tuning-tree-depth-and-number-of-trees/35012011#35012011

Comment: You can also use the max_depth parameter as the regularization parameter to reduce the overfiting

Comment: For machine leaning algorithms, I believe that if it can fit, it will overfit. However, what we can do is to tune the parameters to reduce the risk of overfitting.

Comment: I know the question is very old, but I found [this](https://mljar.com/blog/random-forest-overfitting/) article that explains well why Random forests can overfit in certain scenarios, and that pruning generally fixes this issue

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To avoid over-fitting in random forest, the main thing you need to do is optimize a tuning parameter that governs the number of features that are randomly chosen to grow each tree from the bootstrapped data. Typically, you do this via $k$-fold cross-validation, where $k \in \{5, 10\}$, and choose the tuning parameter that minimizes test sample prediction error. In addition, growing a larger forest will improve predictive accuracy, although there are usually diminishing returns once you get up to several hundreds of trees.

Comment: Thank you. Is there some tutorial which shows how to optimize these parameters?

Comment: You will need to register for Stanford online courses, which is pretty simple, but here is a video tutorial for doing it in R: https://class.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/Winter2014/courseware/4cd5971758e84840b24d91c763df6ce8/e9481751b91d4f25b7a6d98fa5b7d371/

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly we use the cross validation to ascertain the number of features that go into the random forest model as opposed to the number of features that the model will try at every step. Correct ?

Comment: It is the number of features randomly chosen from the full set that are chosen as split candidates at each split. There are helpful functions for optimizing this tuning parameter, such as `randomForest::tuneRF`

Comment: I would argue against this answer: two of the appealing features of RFs are that it is difficult to overfit them and the default parameters are usually fairly good. This answer seem to imply that the RF are sensitive to the defaults which is rarely the case

Comment: Difficult but not impossible to overfit. My post may imply to you that RFs are sensitive to the defaults but you're putting words in my mouth. Read the comment again. It suggests, with reference to a fairly authoritative text, that mtry is an important tuning parameter. It goes on to explain that the number of trees you grow is not an important tuning parameter, but just to make sure you grow a fairly large one.

Comment: I'll add that the clause "To avoid over-fitting in random forest,..." does not imply anything about how sensitive random forests are to tuning. But it's hard to argue that tuning mtry does *not* avoid over-fitting.

Comment: Empirically, I have not found it difficult at all to overfit random forest, guided random forest, regularized random forest, or guided regularized random forest. They regularly perform very well in cross validation, but poorly when used with new data due to over fitting. I believe it has to do with the type of phenomena being modeled. It's not much of a problem when modeling a mechanical process, but with something like a behavioral model I get much more stable results with a well-specified regression.

Comment: Overfitting is when you have your train << oob/cv score. This is often the case for the RFs I have used. People keep repeating that Brieman thinks there is no overfitting in RF. He means that you increase `n_estimators` or increase `max_sample_size`  and you wont overfit as a result of increasing this parameter. But A simplest example of overfitting is when you have `min_sample_leafs`=1. This means the tree in the end could potentially have one leaf for each sample. This 100% will overfit. In this case you will have 100% training score and a not so 100% oob/cv score.

Comment: @Hack-R if they overfit, why would they perform well in cross-validation?

Comment: @bob Although cross-val is a method to try to reduce overfitting and sensitive performance metric values, the data is still the same as the training data set. For this reason the ML companies like DataRobot, Dataiku, W&B, etc. typically use both cross-validation and a holdout. Sometimes you'll get consistent results for CV and holdout but about as often you don't. When you don't you need to do data cleaning, feature engineering, rethink partitioning, tune the models, etc.

Answer (score 45):

How are you getting that 99% AUC on your training data? Be aware that there's a difference between

```
predict(model)
```

and

```
predict(model, newdata=train)
```

when getting predictions for the training dataset. The first option gets the *out-of-bag* predictions from the random forest. This is generally what you want, when comparing predicted values to actuals on the training data.

The second treats your training data as if it was a new dataset, and runs the observations down each tree. This will result in an artificially close correlation between the predictions and the actuals, since the RF algorithm generally doesn't prune the individual trees, relying instead on the ensemble of trees to control overfitting. So don't do this if you want to get predictions on the training data.

Comment: I was using predict(model, data=train). I have now switched to predict(model) and my auc has dropped to 87%. Is this a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: Thank you! I found that this was the issue for me as well. I posted a follow-up question on what measure to use as 'training error' for RF models here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162353/what-measure-of-training-error-to-use-for-random-forests

Comment: Great, thank you!! I was doing this mistake too! To @Abhi: it's a good thing, because the previous AUC was nonsensically high. This one is more realistic. Try cross-validation and measure AUC on that and you will probably see similar value.

Comment: Imagine that we train a RF with a training dataset and we saved the model, and we forgot to save the training dataset. So we lost the training dataset.... But one day we meet it again without knowing that it is the training dataset, what should we do to evaluate the this dataset?

Answer (score 11):

For decision trees there are two ways of handling overfitting: (a) don't grow the trees to their entirety (b) prune

The same applies to a forest of trees - don't grow them too much and prune.

I don't use `randomForest` much, but to my knowledge, there are several parameters that you can use to tune your forests:

- `nodesize` - minimum size of terminal nodes
- `maxnodes` - maximum number of terminal nodes
- `mtry` - number of variables used to build each tree (thanks @user777)

Comment: And `mtry`, the number of variables the algorithm draws to build each tree, by default the square root of the number of features total.

Comment: I would leave maxnodes and lower sampsize instead. Both decresing maxnodes and sampsize give trees with less depth and a more robust forest, sampsize however lower tree correlation also, and the forest will likely converge to lower cross-validated prediction error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997134/random-forest-tuning-tree-depth-and-number-of-trees/35012011#35012011

Answer (score 3):

Try to tune **max_depth** parameter in ranges of [5, 15] but not more than this because if you take large depth there is a high chance of overfitting.

Comment: There's no particular reason to believe that every problem will have the optimal depth in the range [5,15]. Some problems are extremely complex, so a deep tree is required to achieve the desired result.