# Random Forest accuracy 0.98, is it too much?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am using about 256 predictors and target is sales. I am using a software called Alteryx which is R based. I have tried to run Random Forest, Spline model and Neural nets on same data.

I used partitioning to create test and training data sets.

I am fairly new to field, hence I am not sure how to compare performance of these models.

I was advised to compare Pearson correlation coefficient between predicted and actual value for all models and select the best one.

Although I am new, from what I have learned, I don't think its a good way to compare models.Pearson for Forest model is about 0.98 and for neural nets it's about 0.91. both figures are for testing set.

**Is there any better way to compare and cross validate models?**

Should I use R squared value/ AIC to compare?Is there any other manual way to compare models?

I have predicted and actual values for training data sets for all models, is there any way to compare using those?

Comment: Is this cross-validated accuracy? I ask because your model will obviously perform very well when you test it on the same data that you trained it on...

Comment: See my answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112052/1569

Comment: Please provide more info on your data and experimental setup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Forest - How to handle overfitting](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111968/random-forest-how-to-handle-overfitting)

Comment: In such cases, when predictive accuracy is implausibly high, it's worth checking whether any predictors are actually part and parcel of the outcome.  E.g., if Y = Sales and one predictor is Sales in Region A.