# Huge overfitting with Random Forests and Boosted Trees?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, random-forest, boosting, overfitting

In the following picture, the boxplots represent a performance metric (the closer to 1, the better) recorded for 50 runs of cross-validation, and the black filled circles are the **training values** of the models (performance of the models on the full data set).

[image]

It seems to me that the "white model" (Random Forests) strongly overfits in case #2 (and possibly in case #3)? Simply by comparing the training and testing values, can I reasonably infer that?

On a separate note, it seems that the "grey model" (Boosted Trees) has a slight tendency to underfit (in light of cases #1 and #3)? If yes, does it mean that this model is not optimal - and that, therefore, my best model selection procedure is also not optimal? .

PS: in case it matters, the models are used for multiclass classification, the performance metric is the [Rank Probability Skill Score (RPSS)](http://iri.columbia.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/scoredescriptions.pdf), and each run of cross-validation randomly leaves 5% of the observations out (~150 observations).

Comment: For RFs, one thing that might inflate the test-set performance is that I used the data=data.train argument in the R command (see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111968/random-forest-how-to-handle-overfitting?rq=1) 
That does not change the meaning of my question, but might explain why the differences between train/test are so extreme for RFs

Comment: As per my answer to the linked question, `predict(model, data.train)` gives a meaningless result for random forests. Use `predict(model)` to get honest predictions for your training data.

Comment: there's a typo in my comment above: it should read ..."inflate the **train-test** performance"...