# Prediction problem in randomForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to use the `randomForest` algorithm in R. When I apply the algorithm to my database, I got the following result:

```r
library(randomForest)

x = data[,1:8]
y = data[,9]

model <- randomForest(y ~ ., x)
model
```

```
Call:
 randomForest(formula = y ~ ., data = x) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 23.7%
Confusion matrix:
    0   1 class.error
0 430  70   0.1400000
1 112 156   0.4179104
```

The answer is according to the prediction:

```r
pred <- predict(model, type = "class")
table(pred, y)
1-mean(pred==y)
```

```
  y
pred   0   1
   0 430 112
   1  70 156
[1] 0.2369792
```

Here, above,  we have the same error rate.
However, when I try a new prediction with the explicit initial x values, the result is different:

```r
pred2 <- predict(model, newdata = x, type = "class")
table(pred2, y)
1-mean(pred2==y)
```

```
     y
pred2   0   1
    0 500   0
    1   0 268
[1] 0
```

I've already tried the same procedure with the `glm` function, and in both cases, the result were the same.
What is the difference between the two predictions above?

Comment: The way you used the formula argument in the RF model is weird, `randomForest(y ~ ., x)` y is a vector and all the predictors are in x. The formula argument expects all variables in the same data frame when you provide a formula. Use `randomForest(y=y,x=x)`.

Comment: I changed to the way you said but I didn't change a thing.

Comment: Can you post a chunk of your data or a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case (`predict(model, type='class')` we look at OOB errors and in the second case (`predict(model, type='class', data = x)` the training data are treated as new data. This second option will artificially inflate the goodness-of-fit from the RF model. CV.SE has very relevant thread under: *[What measure of training error to report for Random Forests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162353/what-measure-of-training-error-to-report-for-random-forests)* I would suggest reading through it
.